# DEPLOYMENT_ID not created for Sybase in DATABASECHANGELOG, liquibase 3.5.1

Tags: sybase, liquibase

Just testing Liquibase 3.5.1 with Sybase and find that I get an exception after my first table is created and liquibase attempts to update the DATABASECHANGELOG.

My research seems to indicate that the new DEPLOYMENT_ID column is not added in the CreateDatabaseChangeLogTableGeneratorSybase

```
@Override
    public Sql[] generateSql(CreateDatabaseChangeLogTableStatement statement, Database database, SqlGeneratorChain sqlGeneratorChain) {
        return new Sql[] {
                new UnparsedSql("CREATE TABLE " + database.escapeTableName(database.getLiquibaseCatalogName(), database.getLiquibaseSchemaName(), database.getDatabaseChangeLogTableName()) + " (ID VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, " +
                "AUTHOR VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, " +
                "FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                "DATEEXECUTED " + DataTypeFactory.getInstance().fromDescription("datetime", database).toDatabaseDataType(database) + " NOT NULL, " +
                "ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, " +
                "EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, " +
                "MD5SUM VARCHAR(35) NULL, " +
                "DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) NULL, " +
                "COMMENTS VARCHAR(255) NULL, " +
                "TAG VARCHAR(255) NULL, " +
                "LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20) NULL, " +
                "CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255) NULL, " +
                "LABELS VARCHAR(255) NULL, " +
                "PRIMARY KEY(ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME))",
                        getAffectedTable(database))
        };  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
```

The table that does get created is indeed missing DEPLOYMENT_ID:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.MCH_DATABASE_CHANGE_LOG;

CREATE TABLE dbo.DATABASECHANGELOG
(
   ID             varchar(150)   NOT NULL,
   AUTHOR         varchar(150)   NOT NULL,
   FILENAME       varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
   DATEEXECUTED   datetime       NOT NULL,
   ORDEREXECUTED  int            NOT NULL,
   EXECTYPE       varchar(10)    NOT NULL,
   MD5SUM         varchar(35),
   DESCRIPTION    varchar(255),
   COMMENTS       varchar(255),
   TAG            varchar(255),
   LIQUIBASE      varchar(20),
   CONTEXTS       varchar(255),
   LABELS         varchar(255)
);
```

The exception I'm getting:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid column name 'DEPLOYMENT_ID'.
 [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO [dbo].[MTA_DATABASE_CHANGE_LOG] ([ID], [AUTHOR], [FILENAME], [DATEEXECUTED], [ORDEREXECUTED], [MD5SUM], [DESCRIPTION], [COMMENTS], [EXECTYPE], [CONTEXTS], [LABELS], [LIQUIBASE], [DEPLOYMENT_ID]) VALUES ('create-message-table', 'TAA.team', 'com/mcorp/tools/integration/persistence/liquibase/MTA.db.changelog-create.xml', GETDATE(), 1, '7:7fd70289c6cfc92aa9a8b2206743f4bf', 'createTable tableName=MTA_MESSAGES; sql', '', 'EXECUTED', 'table', NULL, '3.5.1', '7855321615')]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:301)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:107)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:97)
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.setExecType(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:341)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.markChangeSetExecStatus(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1134)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:62)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
    at com.mcorp.tools.integration.persistence.liquibase.LiquibaseExecutor.execute(LiquibaseExecutor.java:195)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'DEPLOYMENT_ID'.

    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2893)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2335)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:638)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:809)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.execute(JtdsStatement.java:1282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:299)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. When 3.5.1 runs for the first time in a database it fails with a "column DEPLOYMENT_ID does not exist" error. But on the second run Liquibase fixes itself. I'd suggest:

1. Just try to run the same Liquibase command again. Then..
2. File a bug to https://liquibase.jira.com/

Comment: I raised :
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2818
I added my patched version of the generator class with which I'm able to run now as a workaround.
and just found another bug related to 3.5.1 and Sybase and raised:

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2819